# How to keep unique months in array of timestamps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to create an array that contains unique months (August 2015, September 2015 etc.). For this I defined the following function that takes an object with timestamps as keys:

```
export function getUniqueMonths(exps) {

  //1. get all keys from expenditures
  const days = Object.keys(exps)

  //2. convert key strings to timestamps
  const daysInt = days.map((day) => (new Date(parseInt(day))))

  //3. return only the "date portion" of the timestamp
  const datePortion = daysInt.map((day) => (new Date(day.toDateString()) ))

  //4. set each datePortion to 1st of month
  const firstOfMonth = datePortion.map((day) => new Date(day.getFullYear(), day.getMonth(), 1)  )

  //5. keep only unique firstOfMonths
  const uniqMonths = [...(new Set(firstOfMonth))]

  return uniqMonths
}
```

However, this function gives me an array like this:

```
[Sat Aug 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time), Sat Aug 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time), Tue Sep 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time), Sat Aug 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time), Sat Aug 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time), ...]
```

I thought getting the date portion of the timestamp (step 3) and setting all dates to first of month (step 4) would do the trick. But I still have duplicates in my array.

What am I missing?

Comment: Sets use equality to determine if two elements are the same. Date's are objects, so equality means they must be the exact same date object, not two different date objects referring to the same point in time. You could convert your Date objects into strings before making the Set and then convert back after.

Comment: Awesome, just adding .toString() in step 4 does the trick. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be overengineering things :) Something like

```
function getUniqueMonths(exps) {
  const uniqueMonths = new Set();
  Object.keys(exps).forEach((timestamp) => {
    const date = new Date(parseInt(timestamp));  // expected to be milliseconds since 1/1/1970
    uniqueMonths.add(`${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()}`);
  });
  return uniqueMonths;
}
```

should get you a Set of unique months in the form of `['2017-12', '2018-0', ...]` (zero-based months as is the JavaScript standard).

If you need `Date` objects, those are trivial to "rehydrate".

Comment: This throws me the error "Uncaught TypeError: date.getFullYear is not a function" - I think because Object.keys returns an array of strings.

Comment: byDay: {
      '1440374400000': [
        {
          id: 'caea6422-d208-4a94-a3a4-ea8b35ab8d39',
          createdAt: 1480510965381,
          updatedAt: 1480510965381, ...} ... ]

Comment: byDay is the exps object and Object.keys(exps) gives me ["1440374400000", "1440720000000", "1443398400000", ...]

Comment: I would replace `uniqueMonths.add(`${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()}`);` by `uniqueMonths.add(date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { year: 'numeric', month: 'long'}));`

Answer (score 1):

Two `Date` objects are not the same object, even if they contain the same timestamp.

Instead, try:

```
//3. keep the year-month portion of the date
const yearMonths = daysInt.map(day => day.getFullYear()+"-"+day.getMonth());
```

Then you can skip `4` and just get the unique year-months from there. These will be returned as `"2015-7"` for August 2015, for example.